# Convertfeaturestographics Tool or Program

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, feature-class

Problem : With over 19 feature classes in our dataset, we need to convert all these featureclasses to graphic . But to do it programmatically, we searched the resources but could not find a Python script for converting features to graphics.

Though below VBA code was available , I hope it wont help us in 10.1

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.0/samples/arcmap/convertfeaturestographics.htm

Mightbe we are missing some trick here ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears VBA is still supported for v10.1, however there are some additional install steps, see link below:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/install-guides/arcgis-desktop/10.1/index.html#//008700000012000000

The recommended workflow is to covert your VBA code to .NET.  There are many forum posts and ESRI how to for doing this migration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about a way to convert the features directly to graphics. But you could do something like this:

1. Put your feature classes in a mxd; either manually or programmatically
2. Create dataDrivenPages, have a look at [ArcGIS Help 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/DataDrivenPages/00s300000030000000/)
3. Export each data driven page to graphic with arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG (or PNG,SVG, ...)

Comment: @ Torsten - Does the above code outputs image format only ? What I would exactly require is the "Drawing graphic" which can be used a selection media in the advanced option in Extract data tool ( Distributed geodatabase)